# regTermTest in R survey package does not appear to produce correct p-values

Tags: r

I am trying to use regTermTest to test for estimated with the survey package in R. This is a simulation study. I simulated 1,000 stratified random samples from a finite population. The correct model is given by `y ~ x + Stratum`, for some covariate x. The intercept varies by stratum. I fit `y ~ x * Stratum` using svyglm() and then ran `regTermTest(myOutput, ~x:Stratum),` to test for the presence of an interaction effect. I also the usual ANOVA using a linear model. The p-values from regTermTest ought to follow a uniform distribution, with 5% of them having values below 5%. Same for the ANOVA. The p-values for the regular linear model worked out, but regTermTest produced p-values that were way too small. The median p-value was 0.02, when it should have been 0.5.

Does anyone know what's going wrong here? And should I have posted this question to Cross-Validated?

Comment: IIRC `regTermTest()` does exactly the same thing as `anova()`. If they both show you the same output, then those are the correct p-values. If you really believe there's something strange, please show your data, your desired output compared to what you actually get.

Comment: anova() compares two likelihood functions, and since svyglm() does not use ML, there is no anova() method for its output. regTermTest() uses Wald statistics to kludge something together.